# Better way to create file for download on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When user create a new record, it will generate  a zip file for user to download later.

However I put the generated file under `public/downloads` ,

The file is generated by external process and

I moved it to the  `public/downloads` manually.

I think its a bad practice,

Is there any gem can help me to put the file on a good location ?

Comment: Better use an external service or else the application size will increase resulting in slower performance .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you store the file on an external service and not on your web servers.
There are many good services for storage. I am using Amazon S3 to handle storage for me.
In order to integrate with S3 you can use any of the following gems:

1. [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)
2. [Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog)
3. [AWS-SDK-Core](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-core-ruby)